# How to set Protractor configuration to run on FireFox and enable CORS

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, firefox, selenium, protractor

I'm running my protractor tests with Chrome and i'd like to run them with Firefox too. Problem is I can't find how to enable CORS in firefox like I do in Chrome.
This is my configuration for Chrome:

```
capabilities:{
    'browserName': 'chrome',
    'chromeOptions': {
        'args': ['--disable-web-security']
    }
},
```

Answer (score 0):

Hate to say it but FireFox doesn't have similar functionality.
In fact, out of the main four browsers (Chrome, Safari, FF and IE), only Chrome and IE will allow you to run with web security disabled and only Chrome from the command line.

Source: I spent a lot of time looking for a way to run each of these browsers with CORS security disabled and failed on all accounts except for Chrome and IE.

Comment: were you able to figure it out for Firefox, Safari and IE?

Comment: I was not. I haven't investigated this since though so maybe things have changed? I highly doubt it though. You can do this for IE though, you have to go into your Internet Options and disable the security in there.

Comment: I was able to get it working for IE but not for firefox.

Answer (score 0):

with selenium webdriverjs we can use this

npm :  https://github.com/saadtazi/firefox-profile-js

```
var FirefoxProfile = require('firefox-profile'),
webdriverjs = require('webdriverjs');

var fp = new FirefoxProfile();
fp.setPreference("security.fileuri.strict_origin_policy", false);
```

And this is the link to set specific firefox profile for Protractor

https://github.com/juliemr/protractor-demo/tree/master/howtos/setFirefoxProfile